# How do I access methods attached to a Schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am experiencing some confusion regarding calling a method that I have attached to a schema in a project that I am working on.  I am essentially accessing a document from the database and trying to compare the hashed password I have stored to the password that was submitted by the user on login.  When I go to try and compare the password though, the method that I attached to the methods object of the schema is nowhere to be found.  It doesn't even throw an error for me telling me that there is no such method.  This is where I am setting the method on the schema:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var vendorSchema = new Schema({
  //Schema properties
});

vendorSchema.pre('save', utils.hashPassword);
vendorSchema.methods.verifyPassword = utils.verifyPassword;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Vendor', vendorSchema);
```

The function I am using as the compare method is a utility function that I created called verifyPassword, which is held in a utility file.  The code for that function is here:

```
verifyPassword: function (submittedPassword) {
    var savedPassword = this.password;

    return bcrypt.compareAsync(submittedPassword, savedPassword);
  }
```

I try to verify the password like this:

```
    var password = req.body.password;
    _findVendor(query)
        .then(function (vendor) {

          return vendor.verifyPassword(password);
        });
```

I have promisified mongoose with bluebird promises if that makes any difference.  I have tried a lot of things, but can't find any answer as to why nothing is happening when I try to invoke this method that I thought I had attached the schema.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which method you are invoking? describe clearly..

Comment: did i answered your question

Answer (score 5):

```
/*VendorSchema.js*/
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var vendorSchema = new Schema({
  //Schema properties
});
vendorSchema.methods.method1= function{
         //Some function definition
};
vendorSchema.statics.method2 = function{
         //Some function definition
};
module.exports = mongoose.model('Vendor', vendorSchema);
```

Lets say i would like to access VendorSchema inside other file:

```
/*anotherfile.js*/
var VendorSchema= require('../VendorSchema.js');
var Vendor = new VendorSchema();
```

As we defined method2 as static you can access method2 inside anotherfile.js by using schemareference object VendorSchema.

```
VendorSchema.method2
```

But method1 is not static you can access method1 inside anotherfile.js using only after creating object instance of schema.

```
Vendor.method1 /*Vendor is object instance of the schema*/
```